# How to grant permissions to write to global secondary index via terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

my colleague has set up terraform to build a dynamo DB table + global secondary index.

```
  global_secondary_index {
    name            = "${lookup(var.archive_metadata, "gsi_name")}"
    hash_key        = "${lookup(var.archive_metadata, "gsi_hash_key")}"
    read_capacity   = "${lookup(var.archive_metadata, "read_capacity")}"
    write_capacity  = "${lookup(var.archive_metadata, "write_capacity")}"
    projection_type = "ALL"
  }
```

We're trying to figure out how to grant write access to a lambda function. We tried this

```
data aws_iam_policy_document "archive_metadata_write" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
      "dynamodb:Describe*",
      "dynamodb:Get*",
      "dynamodb:List*",
      "dynamodb:Query",
      "dynamodb:Scan",
      "dynamodb:PutItem",
      "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_dynamodb_table.archive_metadata.arn}",
      "${aws_dynamodb_table.archive_metadata.global_secondary_index}"
    ]
  }
}
```

No luck.

Also tried

```
"${aws_dynamodb_table.archive_metadata.global_secondary_index.gsi_name}"
```

and

```
 "${aws_dynamodb_table.archive_metadata.global_secondary_index.arn}"
```

Answer (score 17):

What ended up working was

```
  "${aws_dynamodb_table.archive_metadata.arn}/index/*"
```

Feels a bit hacky. If anyone else has a better idea, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: According to the docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html#access-policy-examples-for-sdk-cli.example4 - that's the correct way of doing it. So it's not a hack.